# « Surprisingly, perhaps,... » et « Étonnamment, peut-être,... »

Tags: traduction, anglais, adverbes

> Surprisingly, perhaps, Matlab gives a solution to this over-determined system.
>
> Étonnamment, peut-être, Matlab donne une solution à ce système surdéterminé.

« Étonnamment » peut-il être employé au début de cette phrase ?

Comment: Le rythme de cette phrase, *étonnamment* puis *peut-être*, à mon avis suggére que ce n'est pas si étonnant  que ça. Les systèmes linéaires avec plus d'équations que d'inconnues ont toujours une solution au sens des moindres carrés, même si en général pas de solutions au sens classique ! L'ordre des mots ici est important pour respecter cette nuance dans la traduction. Un commentaire, pas une réponse, pour ne pas effrayer les lecteurs

Comment: @Damien, ce commentaire est une réponse ! Oui, c'est ça : l'ajustement par la méthode des moindres carrés permet la solution:-)!

Comment: @Damien, by the way:-)! Peut-on employer les termes surdéterminé et sous-déterminé parlant d'un système des équations ? (Mes collègues me disent non mais je veux d'autres opinions vu que ces termes se rencontrent comme le montre un googling).

Comment: @Dimitris Ce sont des termes que j'utilise souvent. J'ai mis un lien dans un commentaire de ma réponse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Le rythme de cette phrase, *étonnamment* puis *peut-être*, suggère que ce n'est pas si étonnant que ça. Les systèmes linéaires avec plus d'équations que d'inconnues (les systèmes surdéterminés) ont toujours une solution au sens des moindres carrés, même si en général pas de solutions au sens classique !

L'ordre des mots ici est important pour respecter cette nuance dans la traduction. Ce comportement de Matlab n'est pas étonnant pour un spécialiste.

Comment: Puisque les mathématiques intéressent tant de monde ici, voici un lien : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-solution

Answer (score 0):

Il n'y a pas de problème à cet emploi en début de phrase mais il est plus habituel de lier l'adverbe modificateur  sans ambiguïté à « étonnamment » en le plaçant avant et sans virgule.

- Peut-être étonnamment, Matlab donne une solution à ce système surdéterminé.

Cet ngram montre l'ordre préféré, sans virgule, pour la combinaison « peut-être trop rapidemment » : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peut-%C3%AAtre+trop+rapidement%2Ctrop+rapidement+peut-%C3%AAtre&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeut%20-%20%C3%AAtre%20trop%20rapidement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrop%20rapidement%20peut%20-%20%C3%AAtre%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpeut%20-%20%C3%AAtre%20trop%20rapidement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrop%20rapidement%20peut%20-%20%C3%AAtre%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @Fólkvangr Je crois que cela n'est pas vrai ; un adverbe s'utilise pour modifier un autre adverbe et on peut même en utiliser plusieurs; voilà par exemple la combinaison « peut-être trop rapidement » https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=peut-%C3%AAtre+trop+rapidement&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpeut%20-%20%C3%AAtre%20trop%20rapidement%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpeut%20-%20%C3%AAtre%20trop%20rapidement%3B%2Cc0 La phrase « Peut-être trop rapidement, il a dit ne pas avoir d'intérêt.» me parait tout à fait correcte.

Comment: @Fólkvangr : *P'têt' ben... qu'si!*. Et, peut-être de façon surprenante, peut-être de façon contraire à mon habitude, peut-être inhabituellement pour moi, peut-être étonnamment donc... je pluzunifie cette réponse.

Comment: @Fólkvangr : D'accord. Je vois ce que vous voulez dire. Dans le cas particulier de l'OP, je crois qu'*étonnant* peut-être appliqué également à l'un et à l'autre. Si un logiciel trouve une solution à un truc réputé insoluble, tout pourra justement être dit *étonnant* aussi bien le résultat que la façon d'y parvenir.